# Can the `recvfrom` function be used to check whether there have been any previous data sent to a socket? Or does it need to be actively listening?

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

I have a `while(1)` loop that uses `recvfrom` to get data that has been sent to a domain socket from another process (P2).

The while loop needs to do 2 things, firstly listen for incoming data from P2, and secondly run another function `checkVoltage()`.

So it runs a little something like this:

```
while(true)
{
    listenOnSocket() /*listens for 100 u seconds*/
    checkVoltage();
}
```

My issue is this: the `listenOnSocket()` function uses the `recvfrom` function to check for an input from another process. It spends 100usecs listening, then times out and proceeds to run the `checkVoltage()` function. So it spends like 99% of the time in the `listenOnSocket()` function. My issue is that if P2 sends information to the socket during the `checkVoltage()` function, then it will result in an error, stating: `sending datagram message: No such file or directory`.

Is there a way to have this loop check for any data that has been sent to the socket previously? That way if P2 sends data during the `checkVoltage()` function, it will not result in an error.

Thanks.

EDIT:

So the `listenOnSocket()` function creates a socket with the name `FireControl` when I run P1 (the program that receives data from P2) the `FireControl` file vanishes for a split second then reappears. If P2 sends data to P1 during this short period, it results in the error mentioned up top.

So I guess this means I should separate the creation of the socket from the `recvfrom` function, because the short period where the new socket is created it does not exist - if that makes sense.

I'm a dope, I should've separated them in the first place!

EDIT2: Here is `listenOnSocket()`:

```
command listenOnSocket(int timeout, float utimeout) /*Returns null payload when no input is detected*/
{
    command payload;
    int sock;
    socklen_t* length;
    struct sockaddr_un name;
    char buf[1024];

    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = timeout;
    tv.tv_usec = utimeout;

    /* Create socket from which to read. */
    sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) 
    {
        perror("opening datagram socket");
        payload = nullPayload;
    }

    /* Create name. */
    name.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(name.sun_path, NAME);

    unlink(name.sun_path);

    /* Bind the UNIX domain address to the created socket */
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un))) 
    {
        perror("binding name to datagram socket\n");
        payload = nullPayload;
    }

    /*Socket has been created at NAME*/
    if (timeout != 0 || utimeout != 0)
    {
        setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));
    }
    else
    {
        tv.tv_sec = 0;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;
        setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));
    }
    /* Read from the socket */
    if (recvfrom(sock, &payload, sizeof(command), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&name, &length) < 0) /*Less than zero results from a timeout*/
    {
        payload = nullPayload;
    }

    unlink(NAME);   
    return payload;
}
```

and here is the loop that calls it:

```
while (1)
    {
        buffer = getADCValue();

        checkVoltage();

        temp = listenOnSocket(0, 100); /*Look for a new command*/
        doStuffWithTempIfItHasChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "sent to a domain socket" -> given the tag, am I right to assume that you mean UNIX domain socket?

Comment: Also, are you sure that your socket works at all? AFAIK, you shouldn't need to be stuck in `recvfrom` for a `send`/`sendto` call from P2 to complete successfully, the messages should be queued provided that the socket does exist.

Comment: @zneak yes, this is a unix domain socket (running on Raspbian). The sockets definitely do work, in another section of code I run `listenOnSocket` without any timeout, and the program sits on the `recvfrom` function while it waits for input.

Comment: Adding a bit more info to the question now

Comment: I'm assuming you are using `SOCK_DGRAM` due to use of `recvfrom()`. Why do you think you need to `listen()`? Why is `bind()` not sufficient?

Comment: @alvits Apologies if I am misunderstanding, I thought that `bind()` was used to just create the actual socket file that sits on disk, so that other processes know what name to send data to

Comment: Your understanding is correct. `bind()` creates it. The client then needs to `sendto()` this socket, whle the server `recvfrom()` this socket. No `listen()`ing involved.

Comment: Where is your code for `listenOnSocket`? How can we work out what is going on without any code?

Comment: You have to be clear and post whether your socket is connection oriented or datagram. My assumption may not be what you really have.

Comment: To answer your question, yes, on datagram you can `recvfrom()` messages sent by client via `sendto()` without `listen()`ing. However, on socket stream, you need to `listen()` and `accept()` each connections.

Comment: That's the source of your issue. `listenOnsocket()` always deletes and creates a new socket. You should only create the socket once on entry of server code then loop on `recvfrom()`. This create and delete loop will trash anything that is queued in the socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've bound the socket, the datagrams will accumulate in a buffer and can be read later using *recvfrom*.  That said, if the buffer overflows, messages may be discarded.

Answer (score 2):

> I guess this means I should separate the creation of the socket from the recvfrom function, because the short period where the new socket is created it does not exist

That is correct. If you open and close the socket every time in your `listenOnSocket()` socket, (a) you will lose any datagrams that got queued that you didn't read, and (b) sends while the socket is closed will fail ... of course. Nothing for them to send to.